# ModX Get Resources not using template

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Newbie to modx and I am trying to build an image slider in Modx Revo. I am using Get resources but it does not output the template file. What am I doing wrong? This is my code:

```
[[getResources? 
        &resources=`[[*slide-img]]` 
        &parents=`-1` 
        &depth=`0` 
        &limit=`0` 
        &tpl=`slides` 
        &sortby=`FIELD(modResource.id,[[*slide-img]])` 
        &sortdir=`ASC`
        &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvPrefix=`tv.`
    ]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to get all images from ressources in the resource tree. And show them in an image slider.

I guess you will have the javaScript for the image slider already present. So there is how to get the images.

You have a *TV* called **slide-img**, right? Good. Make sure it's *output format* is *text*.

If you refer to that image inside of a page that carries that TV, you call it like this

```
<img src="[[*slide-image]]" alt="some Image" />
```

If you call it in a chunk (what you will do when using getResources), you call the image like this:

```
<img src="[[+tv.slide-image]]" alt="some Image" />
```

See the difference? ***** is for the *TV* inside of the same page, **+** is the correct call for a *placeholder*. So if you're using getResources, it will put everything you query into the placeholders in your microtemplate (we call that *chunk* in MODX terms)

So your getResources call might look like this:

```
[[getResources? 
    &parents=`-1` (the place from where getResources will dig down the tree)
    &depth=`0` (how deep will it dig?)
    &limit=`0` (only the default 5? no! :) )
    &tpl=`slides` (this is your chunk, right?)
    &sortby=`FIELD(modResource.id,[[*slide-img]])` (you will sort by the file name and folder, is that right?)
    &sortdir=`ASC`
    &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvPrefix=`tv.` (right, right, tv. is already the default value)
]]
```

Comment: Very good explanation. I understand it much better now. Thanks Guido

Comment: Guido, do I need to create a unique TV for every image? So [[+tv.slide-image-one]] and [[+tv.slide-image-two]]

Comment: THIS IS MY CHUNK: <div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('[[+tv.slide-img]]')">
   
   <div class="p-responsive center">
       <div class="caption">
           <h2 class="h1 white condensed-bold text-shadow">[[+pagetitle]]</h2>
           <p>[[+description]]</p>
           [[+link_attributes:notempty=`<a title="[[+pagetitle]]" class="mt1 button button-primary" href="[[+link_attributes]]">[[+menutitle]]</a>`]]
       </div>
       [[+introtext:notempty=`<div class="photocaption mt1 small">
           <h4>[[+introtext]]</h4>
       </div>`]]
   </div> 
</div>

Comment: Im trying to figure out how to create 3 slides using a single chunk like the one above, but each slide has a unique image.

Comment: Your chunk that you name in the &tpl parameter IS the microtemplate that will be called for every [[+slide-img]] your getResources call will find.
It is looking good from what I see here, apart from the missing backticks after :norempty. I guess this is just because of the editor here.

getResources works a bit like "foreach" in php. So your approach is good. Try and start with a smaller chunk. Put `[[+pagetitle]]` only, then put a TV like `[[+tv.slide-img]]`.
If the output is as expected, go on and complete the chunk step by step.

Answer (score 0):

getResources is a snippet used primarily to list documents, not images. A document (of type HTML, XML, CSS or JSON, to name a few) is created in the document tree in the manager and represents an example of a resource that you can get with getResources snippet.

Even if it is possible somehow to put an image as a document (which I doubt), it is not a common way anyway. Usually you want to attach an image to a document via template variable of corresponding type. For a slider particularly, you need many images, not one. So, you might need something specific like [Gallery Extra](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/gallery) to manage and output your images. Check out [gallery section](https://modx.com/extras/category/gallery) too. Note that basic version of MODX you have just installed isn't fully functional. We have to install extras to use MODX properly. Usually I install up to 30 extras.

Also your snippet call looks weird to me:

```
&resources=`[[*slide-img]]`
```

I don't know what the content of your template variable `slide-img` is but it should be a comma-separated list of resource ids like `2,4,6,34`. Probably, in your case you have something different like image url and the snippet call silently crashes or just outputs nothing.